# any mac mini for iphone development

Tags: macos, ios-simulator

are all mac minis possible (if not really suitable, like used 1.4 GHz mac mini) feasible for xcode simulator of iphone devel.?  Are all mac minis intel-based?

Answer (score 3):

Early Mac Minis were PowerPC-based and can not be used with the current Xcode tool chain for iPhone. Any Intel Mac Mini is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Mac Minis are Intel based, as of Feb 2006. Any of the Intel versions works just fine. Even with the minimum RAM configurations.